# Moving basepath using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How can I set .htaccess file to redirect users to the other url keeping same folder name, file name?

For example,

If user connects to the address

```
http://previous.com/folder/fileName
```

I want the user to be redirected to

```
http://after.com/folder/fileName
```

keeping all the folder/file information using .htaccess file in the root directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding the following to your htaccess file in the root directory of `previous.com`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^previous\.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://after.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```